# "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I am getting an exception while creating a form using spring forms tag library

"Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute"

The jsp page is index.jsp

```
<%@ include file="views/static_include.jsp" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login to AVA Corp</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form method="POST" commandName="user" action="login.jsp">  
<table>  
    <tbody><tr>  
        <td><form:label path="firstName">Name:</form:label></td>  
        <td><form:input path="firstName"></form:input></td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td><form:label path="age">Age:</form:label></td>  
        <td><form:input path="age"></form:input></td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td colspan="2">  
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">  
        </td>  
        <td></td>  
        <td></td>  
    </tr>  
</tbody></table>    
</form:form> 
</body>
</html>
```

The bean class is:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1949001721422434327L;

    private String firstName;
    private Integer age;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

The controller class is

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView initForm(Model model) {
        return new ModelAndView("index", "user", new Employee());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") Employee employee, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("user", employee); 
        return "UserFormSuccess";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was with the controller method with method type = "get". The value of the request method needs to be the URL mapping of the page on which the form resides e.g. index.jsp in our case so the controller class will be

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView initForm(Model model) {
        return new ModelAndView("index", "user", new Employee());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(@ModelAttribute("user") Employee employee, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("user", employee); 
        return "UserFormSuccess";
    }
}
```